# Multiple elasticsearch python client sending bulk json data to single ES cluster

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am planning to have elasticsearch python client on each of my ec2 servers (around 50-60 ec2 servers) send data to my single ES cluster.
Each python client will send bulk json every second to the ES cluster. Total - 50/60 bulk index every second 
Each bulk json can have upto ~500 documents / ~ 3-4 MB bulk json. Assuming I am using 20 node cluster m4.large or maybe more. 

My question here is

1. How will ES cluster load balance the requests coming from different servers?
2. Requests coming from different servers so frequently, how will that impact my system?
3. elasticsearch vs Curl to the endpoint, which is better?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience 
You should test it with your specific setup.

It depends on:

- How big is your ES cluster
- How big is your database size
- How many replicas do you have
- How many indexing nodes do you have
- Any node/shard aware ids
- How big are your documents
- How complex your custom tokenization/indexing
- Do you have any spikes in sending documents
- How many other queries are running on cluster
- How big is refresh interval

1.
Take a look on data from you servers during test runs

curl localhost:9200/_cat/thread_pool?v=true

```
node_name name                active queue rejected
prodnode  bulk                     0     0        0
prodnode  fetch_shard_started      0     0        0
prodnode  fetch_shard_store        0     0        0
prodnode  flush                    0     0        0
prodnode  force_merge              0     0        0
prodnode  generic                  0     0        0
prodnode  get                      0     0        0
prodnode  index                    0     0        0
prodnode  listener                 0     0        0
prodnode  management               1     0        0
prodnode  refresh                  0     0        0
prodnode  search                   0     0        0
prodnode  snapshot                 0     0        0
prodnode  warmer                   0     0        0
```

2.
From my experience numbers you mentioned should be manageable by cluster.
First issue you could face: bulk rejection ([really good article about this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/why-am-i-seeing-bulk-rejections-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster)).
Could you code tolerate it and resend failed documents? By design bulk queries better to merge to single queue and have one agent sending them to the cluster. Cluster will lock it or throttle if it can not keep up.
It is better to experiment.

3.
Encoding and network delays so much smaller comparing to indexing time and in-cluster communication so it doesn't matter which one will you choose.